# does azure firewall support FQDN inbound traffic filtering in network rules

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-virtual-machine

From azure documentation

> A fully qualified domain name (FQDN) represents a domain name of a
> host or IP address(es). You can use FQDNs in network rules based on
> DNS resolution in Azure Firewall and Firewall policy. This capability
> allows you to filter outbound traffic with any TCP/UDP protocol
> (including NTP, SSH, RDP, and more). You must enable DNS Proxy to use
> FQDNs in your network rules. For more information see Azure Firewall
> DNS settings. [link to documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/fqdn-filtering-network-rules)

I want to use **azure firewall** to filter **inbound** traffic based on **FQDN**, for example allow just traffic from the domain out.example.com to reach our virtual network resources,

is this supported ? The doc mention just outbound traffic.

I can't filter by IP addresses as the resolved IPs of this domain (out.example.com), are not static, and this is the reason behind why I want to use the azure firewall service.

Comment: I am not sure how you want to achieve "filter inbound traffic based on FQDN" as HTTP, SSH, RDP protocols do not have inbound FQDN in headers, only IP addresses.

Comment: As i know, the azure firewall service will check if the traffic is from the resolved IPs of the whitelisted domain, in this case out.example.com, and if so allow the traffic, else deny it

Comment: If you have some alternative, to allow a domain which their resolved IPs are not static, I'm all ears

Answer (score -1):

Azure Firewall supports inbound and outbound filtering. Inbound protection is typically used for non-HTTP/S protocols. For example RDP, SSH, and FTP protocols.
Inbound Internet connectivity can be enabled by configuring Destination Network Address Translation (DNAT). You can configure Azure Firewall Destination Network Address Translation (DNAT) to translate and filter inbound Internet traffic to your subnets. When you configure DNAT, the NAT rule collection action is set to Dnat. Each rule in the NAT rule collection can then be used to translate your firewall public IP address and port to a private IP address and port. DNAT rules implicitly add a corresponding network rule to allow the translated traffic.

Application rules aren't applied for inbound connections. So if you want to filter inbound HTTP/S traffic, you should use Web Application Firewall (WAF). For more information, see [What is Azure Web Application Firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/overview)